# How can I use 'withRouter' and 'history push' in react router v6 for redirecting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, redux

I have registered a button that will take users to a login page on click. I tried using `history.push()` and include values entered into the form, but I do not know how to pass the value of `userData` because I get the following error:

[refers this line payload: err.response.data()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfiEC.png)

When I change this line to display data in the console it is displayed correctly.

*authAction.js*

```
import axios from 'axios';

import { GET_ERRORS} from "./types";
import {useLocation, useNavigate, useParams} from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";


 // Register User
export const registerUser = (userData,history) => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post('/api/users/register', userData)
      .then(res => history.push('/login'))
      // .then(res => console.log(res.data))
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
          type: GET_ERRORS,
          payload: err.response.data()
      })
    );
};`
```

I tried to import the hooks version with router but it brings another error "Invalid Hook Call Warning"

```
export const registerUser = (userData,history) => dispatch => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
  axios
    .post('/api/users/register', userData,navigate)

      .then(res =>navigate('/login'))
      // .then(res => console.log(res.data))
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
          type: GET_ERRORS,
          payload: err.response.data()
      })
    );
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Right now the `payload: err.response.data()` calls are the problem, most likely they should be `payload: err.response.data`.

Comment: nothing changes same error